# Raisins for wine which yield some amount of moisture on squeezing?

Tags: wine, ingredients

I want to make raisin wine that is usable for certain Jewish religious ceremonies. For this the raisins have to yield some amount of moisture on squeezing them.

Which raisins yield some amount of moisture on squeezing.

This question is posted in a slightly different form on [“Mi Yodeya” (Judaism Stackexchange)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/117186/best-raisins-to-make-raisin-wine-for-kiddush)

Comment: Are you looking to buy or dry your grapes to make your own raisins?  I believe, the amount of moisture depends on the drying process used...

Comment: I want to buy the raisins.